# Parse Cloud Code Combine Responses

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my iOS application I have a screen for application activity. This includes Requests from a Requests Database Table and Comments/Likes from a Comments Table.

I am trying to move all my queries to cloud code. In the activity screen, all the requests/likes/comments get populated, right now I am using two network calls to get this data, but **I want to combine the responses of my functions to use one network call to get the users notifications.**

Here is my cloud code functions:

Here I load my notifications objects.

```
   Parse.Cloud.define("loadRequestNotifications", function(request, response){
   var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

   var query1 = new Parse.Query("Requests"); 
   query1.equalTo("requestUser", currentUser);

   var username = currentUser.get("username");     

   var query2 = new Parse.Query("Requests");
   query2.equalTo("driver", username);

    var main1 = Parse.Query.or(query1, query2); 
    main1.include("drivePointer");
    main1.include("drivePointer.driver");
    main1.limit(15);  

     main1.find({
      success: function(results) {
          response.success(results);
       },
      error: function(error) 
      {
        response.error(error);
      }
    }); 
});
```

Here I load the current users likes and comments on there posts.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("loadLikesAndCommentsNotifications", function(request, response) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

    var query3 = new Parse.Query("Posts"); 
    query3.equalTo("driver", currentUser); 

    var query4 = new Parse.Query("Posts");
    query4.equalTo("passengers", currentUser.get("objectId")); 

    var main2 = new Parse.Query.or(query3, query4); 

    var main3  = new Parse.Query("Comments"); 
    main3.matchesKeyInQuery('postId', 'objectId', main2);

    var main4 = new Parse.Query("Comments"); 
    main4.equalTo("commentBy", currentUser); 

    var activityQuery = new Parse.Query.or(main3, main4); 
    activityQuery.include("commentBy");
    activityQuery.limit(15); 

   activityQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
          response.success(results);
       },
      error: function(error) 
      {
        response.error(error);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: i dont understand, in cloud code you can define regular Javascript functions and call them from the Parse.Cloud functions... or you can just put the code in the success: responses to execute more queries....

Comment: I can either call the second function in the success block of the first or probably just execute the queries in there as well, my problem is just getting the results in both functions into one single response.

Comment: If I understand correct you want to send ONE response from two separate functions... are you sure that they start executing at the same time and have exactly the same runtime or do you wanna experience deadlock... I believe that "results" is a string that you can connect with another string like response.success(results + results2);

Comment: It can be one function or two functions, i just want to get both results of the two different queries into one response. "results" is the results of the query, so all the data from the query.